# how sticky 2 columns with using horizontal and vertical scrolling in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I want to stick 2 column with all section and scroll vertical and horizontal 
in my case I have stick 1 column .

```
  let numberOfColumns = 11
var itemAttributes : NSMutableArray!
var itemsSize : NSMutableArray!
var contentSize : CGSize!

override func prepareLayout() {
    if self.collectionView?.numberOfSections() == 0 {
        return
    }

    if (self.itemAttributes != nil && self.itemAttributes.count > 0) {
        for section in 0..<self.collectionView!.numberOfSections() {
            let numberOfItems : Int = self.collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(section)
            for index in 0..<numberOfItems {

                if (section != 0 && index != 0) && (section != 0 && index != 1)     {
                    continue
                }

                let attributes : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: section))

                if section == 0   {
                    var frame = attributes.frame
                    frame.origin.y = self.collectionView!.contentOffset.y
                    attributes.frame = frame
                }

                if index == 0  {
                    var frame = attributes.frame
                    frame.origin.x = self.collectionView!.contentOffset.x
                    attributes.frame = frame
                }



               print ("index : \(index) | section : \(section)")


            }
        }
        return
    }

    if (self.itemsSize == nil || self.itemsSize.count != numberOfColumns) {
        self.calculateItemsSize()
    }

    var column = 0
    var xOffset : CGFloat = 0
    var yOffset : CGFloat = 0
    var contentWidth : CGFloat = 0
    var contentHeight : CGFloat = 0

    for section in 0..<self.collectionView!.numberOfSections() {
        let sectionAttributes = NSMutableArray()

        for index in 0..<numberOfColumns {
            let itemSize = self.itemsSize[index].CGSizeValue()
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: section)
            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: indexPath)
            attributes.frame = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(xOffset, yOffset, itemSize.width, itemSize.height))


            if (section == 0 && index == 0)   {
                attributes.zIndex = 1024;
            } else  if (section == 0 || index == 0) {
                attributes.zIndex = 1023
            }






            if section == 0 {
                var frame = attributes.frame
                frame.origin.y = self.collectionView!.contentOffset.y
                attributes.frame = frame
            }

            if index == 0  {
                var frame = attributes.frame
                frame.origin.x = self.collectionView!.contentOffset.x
                attributes.frame = frame 
            }




            print ("index1 : \(index) | section1 : \(section)")

            sectionAttributes.addObject(attributes)


            xOffset += itemSize.width
            column += 1

            if column == numberOfColumns {
                if xOffset > contentWidth {
                    contentWidth = xOffset
                }

                column = 0
                xOffset = 0
                yOffset += itemSize.height
            }
        }
        if (self.itemAttributes == nil) {
            self.itemAttributes = NSMutableArray(capacity: self.collectionView!.numberOfSections())
        }
        self.itemAttributes .addObject(sectionAttributes)
    }

    var attributes : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = self.itemAttributes.lastObject?.lastObject as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
    contentHeight = attributes.frame.origin.y + attributes.frame.size.height
    self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentWidth, contentHeight)
}

override func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
    return self.contentSize
}

override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes! {
    return self.itemAttributes[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
}

override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    if self.itemAttributes != nil {
        for section in self.itemAttributes {

            let filteredArray  =  section.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(

                NSPredicate(block: { (evaluatedObject, bindings) -> Bool in
                    return CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, evaluatedObject!.frame)
                })
                ) as! [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]


            attributes.appendContentsOf(filteredArray)

        }
    }

    return attributes
}

override func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func sizeForItemWithColumnIndex(columnIndex: Int) -> CGSize {
    var text : String = ""
    switch (columnIndex) {
    case 0:
        text = "Col 0"
    case 1:
        text = "Col 1"
    case 2:
        text = "Col 2"
    case 3:
        text = "Col 3"
    case 4:
        text = "Col 4"
    case 5:
        text = "Col 5"
    case 6:
        text = "Col 6"
    default:
        text = "Col 7"
    }

    let size : CGSize = (text as NSString).sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17.0)])
    let width : CGFloat = size.width + 40
    return CGSizeMake(width, 30)
}

func calculateItemsSize() {
    self.itemsSize = NSMutableArray(capacity: numberOfColumns)
    for index in 0..<numberOfColumns {
        self.itemsSize.addObject(NSValue(CGSize: self.sizeForItemWithColumnIndex(index)))
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au9qT.png)

In this case I have one cell in stick and I want to add 2 other cell to stick .. how I can do it ??